# Why my code do not allow me to insert a node inside the binary search tree?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I tried to make an implementation from a header (which i cannot change) and In there I am to implement Binary search tree.
And I crossed into a problem with with my implementation of the Insert function.
The function only receives a value of string.
But somehow I need to move down the tree with no node parameters in order to do so.
How is this possible?

The header is:

```
class BSNode
{
public:
    BSNode(string data);
    BSNode(const BSNode& other);
    ~BSNode();
    void insert(string value);
    bool isLeaf() const;
    string getData() const;
    BSNode* getLeft()const ;
    BSNode* getRight() const; 
private:
    BSNode* _left;
    BSNode* _right;
    string _data;
};
```

The implementions are:

```
void BSNode::insert(string value)
{
    _data.clear();
    _data.assign(value);

}


BSNode::BSNode(string data)
{
    _data.clear();
    _data.assign(data);
    _right = NULL;
    _left = NULL;
}


BSNode::BSNode(const BSNode& other)
{
    _data.clear();
    _data.assign(other._data);
    _right = other._right;
    _left = other._left;
}
```

Comment: The post is tagged as a binary tree but is it a binary search tree?

Comment: What does the node know about inserting? The tree is made of nodes. You should have another structure, such as `BTree`, having one Node as a root.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing inspiration from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion, I see your implementation of `BSNode::insert()` to be something like:

```
void BSNode::insert(string value)
{
   if ( value < this->_data )
   {
      if ( _left != nullptr )
      {
         _left->insert(value);
      }
      else
      {
         _left = new BSNode(value);
      }
   }
   else if ( this->_data < value )
   {
      if ( _right != nullptr )
      {
         _right ->insert(value);
      }
      else
      {
         _right = new BSNode(value);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // The value is already there. There is nothing to do.
   }
}
```

Comment: Thats brilliant! Thank you very much!

Comment: Should an `insert` method cover the case that the value to be inserted is already there?  If it should and if the way you should "cover" that case is to do nothing, that can be accomplished by changing your top level `else` to `else if ( this->_data < value)`.  If you want it "cover" it with some other behavior, that could be right.  But ignoring such cases is bad software engineering.

Comment: After that edit, I still disagree for both style and efficiency reasons.  Checking `==` up front is worse for several reasons vs. my suggestion of reversing the sides of the `<` test only after the first `<` was false.  If you want a final `else { // do nothing }` for maximum clarity, that is also good.  (specific to `std::string`, even better efficiency is possible by calling `compare` once rather than comparing twice)

Comment: hmm... I agree with @JSF it does add values insdie even if they are already inside the tree which is a big no no

Comment: @TotalyNotUbisoft, The answer was corrected right after I commented on that and long before you did.  Look again.